# How to show activity indicator in Google Maps SDK using swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps

I have an application in which I use **Google Maps SDK** using **swift 3**. In this application, I need to show the activity indicator when the map is loading to show the current location of the user. 
I tried to add the activity indicator in the view controller and linking it to the GMSMapView. But still the activity indicator won't appear.

In this application, I also use web service such that it receives a bundle of coordinates as a response from the server. Now to implement this also I need to show the activity indicator so as to tell the user that the application is busy in fetching the response.

I just need to implement the activity indicator in my application.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You!!

Code:

```
var currentLatitude:Double!
var currentLongitude:Double!
var locationManager:CLLocationManager!
var map = GMSMapView()

@IBOutlet var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!


override func loadView() {

    print("loadView called")

    // Enable some map settings

    map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    map.settings.myLocationButton = true
    map.settings.compassButton = true
    map.settings.scrollGestures = true
    map.settings.zoomGestures = true
    map.delegate = self

    view = map
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("ViewDidLoad called")

    activityIndicator.startAnimating()

    // Configuring location manager.

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    print("locationManager function called")

    // Fetch current location coordinates

    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = (locationManager.location?.coordinate)!
    currentLatitude = locValue.latitude
    currentLongitude = locValue.longitude
    print("Current Location = \(currentLatitude!), \(currentLongitude!)")

    // Zoom to current location

    let target = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLatitude!, longitude: currentLongitude!)
    map.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: target, zoom: 17)

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

Comment: Update with your code

Comment: @AravindBhuvanendran I have updated my code. This is the code where I get current location.

Comment: Where is the activity indicator show/hide code

Comment: You may use SVProgressHUD to implement a custom activity indicator https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD

Comment: @AravindBhuvanendran I had done this but this was of no use.

Comment: @AravindBhuvanendran Okay let me see that link. Will let you know.

Comment: This thing works for Google places -  // Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
  `func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
  }

  func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
  }` . Google for GMap

Comment: It's not the network activity indicator the OP asks about an activity indicator.

Comment: Are you using storyboard? If so make sure your `UIActivityIndicatorView` isn't behind the map.